# In Django, does MyModel.objects.get(my_field=x) equals MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=x).get()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-queryset

I'm currently working on `Django 1.4` and I have a simple question:

Is:

```
MyModel.objects.get(my_field=x)
```

exactly the same (in results, behaviour, etc) as:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=x).get()
```

Does the last one could make some troubles in some particularly cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions mean absolutely the same. Let's explore the source code.

First of all, model manager ("objects" part) is a class [created from a `QuerySet` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py#L244) using [`from_queryset()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.from_queryset). This means that there is the same [`get()` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L359) called in both cases.

Also, `get()` first makes a `filter()` call with all the arguments passed in:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

<sup>Then, it checks how many objects were returned and, depending on the count, decides whether to throw `DoesNotExist` or `MultipleObjectsReturned`.</sup>

Which means that:

```
MyModel.objects.get(my_field=x)
```

is being transformed into:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=x).get()
```